# How to preserve folder structure and filename while downloading using wget?

Tags: web, web-scraping, download, wget

There's a file named links.txt which has different links from i am trying to fetch the links and download them using wget

Command shown below

```
wget -i links.txt -nc -c -x
```

The folder depth is quite a lot and the end result is that the file being downloaded have their names shortened for some reason.
I don't know if its a character limit in linux or something or a wget thing but i would ideally want the exact folder structure and filename to be retained.
Well the folder structure is fine as of now , only issue is the files names are getting shortened .

Lets say for example the actual fileName is - `this_is_the_whole_fileName.mp4`

the downloaded file would be named - `this_is`

FileName is only partially mentioned and the file extension is also absent

On another note - Aria2 doesn't shorten the filesnames and work well for most part , only issue there is that some files take time to start downloading and Aria2 gives error in such cases

Comment: I find it odd that it's so hard to find an answer to this. Shortening the filename is fine, but you'd think `wget` would keep the existing extension if it could.